# How to merge multiple imported GLTF object into one object in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, render, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

The problem is that the website is laggy, becuase I am rendering thousands of objects. I am trying to solve this problem to get better UX.
I am importing 1 GLTF object (myModel). I also have a json file (myJson), which contains how much object and where should I place them. It also contains if the object needs to be rotated.
I think if i could merge all objects into 1, then the website would be not laggy.
How could I do that?
**The whole js code:**

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import myJson from './output.json';

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
);
camera.position.set(10, 10, 10);
const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
orbit.update();

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const assetLoader = new GLTFLoader();
let model = null

assetLoader.load("./myModel.gltf", function (gltf) {
    model = gltf.scene;

    let objects = []

    if (model) {
        for (let i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {
            let XCoordinate = myJson[i].XCoordinate
            let YCoordinate = myJson[i].YCoordinate

            let myModel = model.clone()
            objects.push(myModel)
            objects[objects.length - 1].position.set(XCoordinate, 0, YCoordinate);
            scene.add(objects[objects.length - 1]);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            if (myJson[i].needRotate) {
                objects[i].rotateX(Math.PI / 2)
            } else {
                objects[i].rotateX(-Math.PI / 2)
            }
        }
    }

}, undefined, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});



function animate() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
animate();

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});
```

Comment: Hi, merge into one object doesn't solve your problem, because there will be still same number of triangles to render. How big is model which you are cloning? If you clone object in three js, it's still sharing materials and geometry definition (so it's memory and performance effience clone).